# Nullable DateTime in Where Clause in EF Linq Query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Hi I have a table where there is a RespondBy property which is of DateTime and is Nullable. Here is the linq I'm trying to run over EF6:

```
IEnumerable<Enquiry> ASAPEnquiries = db.Enquiries
       .Where(enq => enq.RespondBy == null && enq.JobCostings.Count == 0)
       .OrderBy(enq => enq.FlReference);
```

However, when I run `if (ASAPEnquiries.Count() > 0)` I get an error stating `Nullable object must have a value.` How would one query the database using linq if you want to check null DateTime columns?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

The SQL that is produced by EF when tested in MSSMS brings back the desired result FYI. SQL Produced:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[FlReference] AS [FlReference], 
    [Project1].[EnquiryDate] AS [EnquiryDate], 
    [Project1].[ContactName] AS [ContactName], 
    [Project1].[ProjectReference] AS [ProjectReference], 
    [Project1].[EnquiryDetails] AS [EnquiryDetails], 
    [Project1].[RespondBy] AS [RespondBy], 
    [Project1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Project1].[Created] AS [Created], 
    [Project1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
    [Project1].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
    [Project1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
    [Project1].[Enquiry_Customer] AS [Enquiry_Customer], 
    [Project1].[Enquiry_EnquiryStatus] AS [Enquiry_EnquiryStatus]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[FlReference] AS [FlReference], 
        [Extent1].[EnquiryDate] AS [EnquiryDate], 
        [Extent1].[ContactName] AS [ContactName], 
        [Extent1].[ProjectReference] AS [ProjectReference], 
        [Extent1].[EnquiryDetails] AS [EnquiryDetails], 
        [Extent1].[RespondBy] AS [RespondBy], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
        [Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
        [Extent1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
        [Extent1].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
        [Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
        [Extent1].[Enquiry_Customer] AS [Enquiry_Customer], 
        [Extent1].[Enquiry_EnquiryStatus] AS [Enquiry_EnquiryStatus], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[JobCostings] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[JobCosting_Enquiry]) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Enquiries] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    WHERE ([Project1].[RespondBy] IS NULL) AND (0 = [Project1].[C1])
    ORDER BY [Project1].[FluidReference] ASC
```

Also, if I iterate over the collection, I get no error so it seems to be something to do with calling .Count() on the collection.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I sort of understand why the error is occuring, I just do not know the best practise to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Try this:`var ASAPEnquiries = db.Enquiries
       .Where(enq => !enq.RespondBy.HasValue)
       .OrderBy(enq => enq.FlReference).ToList();` just to track down the error.  Tell us if you get any errors when you step over that line.

Comment: can you try `enq => enq.RespondBy != null `  to see what haeppens

Comment: @Robert, Yeah, the same I'm afraid.

Comment: @erkaner It works but obviously I get all the records I do not require.

Comment: You get `Nullable object must have a value.` when you step over the line I gave you or when you step over the .Count line?

Comment: @paulpitchford one immediate solution might be to get all records without using this condition, and get the records that has a non-null RespondBy, and using Except() make a substraction.. of course not the ideal solution..

Comment: @erkaner There isn't a general problem with Nullable DateTimes, or checking for them.  Here is a line of code we have running in production just fine `result = result.Where(r => !r.expiration_date.HasValue || r.expiration_date > DateTime.Today);`

Comment: @RobertMcKee [It would seem I have egg on my face](http://morethanthecurve.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/egg-on-face.jpg) The if statement was calling a void where I was then using item.RespondBy.Value.ToShortDateTime(). How embarresing. Thank you all for your help though, I appreciate your time.

Comment: @paulpitchford use `Any()` instead of `ASAPEnquiries.Count() > 0`. It is better to use `Any()` in this type of case and it might also solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem I have [egg on my face.](http://morethanthecurve.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/egg-on-face.jpg) The if statement was calling a void where I was then using item.RespondBy.Value.ToShortDateTime(). How embarresing. Thank you all for your help though, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the HasValue property to check if a Nullable has value.

```
IEnumerable<Enquiry> ASAPEnquiries = db.Enquiries
       .Where(enq => enq.RespondBy.HasValue && enq.JobCostings.Count == 0)
       .OrderBy(enq => enq.FlReference);
```

Comment: I tried IEnumerable<Enquiry> ASAPEnquiries = db.Enquiries.Where(enq => enq.RespondBy.HasValue == false && enq.JobCostings.Count == 0).OrderBy(enq => enq.FluidReference); already and I get the same result as it happens.

Comment: @paulpitchford, ` == false` is unnecessary!

Comment: Is it? Effectively I require records where RespondBy do not have a value. would I use `!enq.RespondBy.HasValue`? <-- This does the same as the above too.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your `Enquiry` class assign value to the `JobCostings` property in it's constructor 
e.g.

```
public Enquiry()
{
    this.JobCostings = new HashSet<JobCosting>();
    //.......
}
```

and try this one :

```
IEnumerable<Enquiry> ASAPEnquiries = db.Enquiries
       .Where(enq => enq.RespondBy == null && !enq.JobCostings.Any())
       .OrderBy(enq => enq.FlReference);
```